# Handling Conditional Messages in a Streamlit App

Tags: python, python-requests, streamlit

I'm building a Streamlit app for a "Guess the Pokémon Challenge." I'm facing two issues:

1. I want to clear the text input field after the user makes a guess, so they don't have to manually clear it.
2. I want to remove the "Sorry, that's not the correct Pokémon name" message after the next new image is generated, clearing it out is not as straightforward as I thought.

```
import streamlit as st
import random, time, requests

# Fetch a list of all Pokémon names
response = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1000")  # Adjust the limit as needed
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    names = [result['name'].capitalize() for result in data['results']]
    # print(names)


# Function to get a random Pokémon name
@st.cache_resource
def get_random_pokemon_name(current_name):
    new_name = random.choice(current_name)
    return new_name


# Choose a random Pokémon name
random_pokemon_name = get_random_pokemon_name(names)

# Fetch Pokémon details by name
url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{random_pokemon_name.lower()}"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    sprite_url = data['sprites']['front_default']

# Streamlit app
st.title("Guess the Pokémon Challenge")

# Display the current Pokémon image and check the guess
if sprite_url:
    st.write(f"Guess the name of this Pokémon:")

    entered_pokemon_name = st.text_input("Enter your guess").strip().capitalize()
    st.image(sprite_url, use_column_width=True, caption=random_pokemon_name)

    # Only check the guess if the user has entered something
    if entered_pokemon_name:
        # st.write(entered_pokemon_name, random_pokemon_name)
        if entered_pokemon_name == random_pokemon_name:
            st.write("Congratulations! You guessed it correctly.")
            st.cache_resource.clear()
            time.sleep(1)
            st.rerun()
        else:
            st.write("Sorry, that's not the correct Pokémon name. Try again.")
```

Comment: The output is a single variable and a string assignment to be displayed according to the condition. `if entered_pokemon_name == random_pokemon_name: msg='Yes!';else: masg='No!';st.write(msg)`